# Get number of items in each category using Ebay SDK

Tags: c#

Bellow Ebay SDK code gives me the categories and its ID only. But i want to get number of items in each category. Any idea what property i need to change on this code bellow then? Thanks

```
eBay.Service.Call.GetCategoriesCall getCategories = new GetCategoriesCall();
            getCategories.ApiContext.SoapApiServerUrl = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi";
            getCategories.ApiContext.ApiCredential.eBayToken = your_token;
            getCategories.CategorySiteID = "0";
            getCategories.LevelLimit = 2;
            getCategories.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);
            var categories = getCategories.GetCategories();
```

Comment: E bay has millions of items. So they might not be providing number of items in each category. You might want to explore different API which gives this information when you send categoryId.

Comment: Whats the best solution then? I want to rank each category as per item numbers. that's my main goal @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: and yes i am talking about only level 1 category not deep more then that @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: If EBay doesn't support that API nothing much can be done.